# rvest set_values doesn't submit all settings

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape results from a speed skating website.  The website has a form to select season, race distance, race location etc.  I have been successful with the following code in getting set_values to set the season, but none of the others seem to get submitted when I run submit_form

Here's the code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://speedskatingresults.com/index.php?p=19&s=1711"
SSResults<- html_session(url)
form <- html_form(SSResults)[[2]]
form <- set_values(form
                  , y ="2016"
                  , d ="2"
                  , t ="9999"
                  , o ="1"
)

final   <- submit_form(SSResults, form)
```

After running submit_form in the above line I get the following message:

```
Submitting with 'y'
```

Settings for d, t, and o, do not seem to be working.  Any suggestions for getting these settings to work as well?

Comment: Can you print your `final` variable? Basically, what you do get when you run `print(final)`?

Comment: So what is the problem. For me this works just fine... using `final %>% read_html %>% html_node("table.skaterdistance") %>% html_table` i got the table without any problem

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Yes, I can get the table no problem, but it's not displaying with any changes other than to the season skated.  i.e. y = 2016 works just fine, but d = 2 should mean that I get 1000m race results in the table.  It's not giving me that, instead I am getting 500m results.  So it doesn't seem to be making any changes to the form other than for y